# Implementing custom IComparer with string

Tags: c#, icomparer

I have a collection of strings in c#, for example;

```
var example = new string[]{"c", "b", "a", "d"};
```

I then with to sort this, but my IComparer method is not working, and looping infinitely by the seems of things.

Basically I need `"b"` to come first, followed by `"c"`, then I dont care about the order of any of the others.

Is this possible using I`Comparer<string>` and the `Compare(string x, string y)` method?

Edit: Code

```
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var sOrder = new string[] { "b", "c" };
        int index_x = -1;
        int index_y = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sOrder.Length;i++)
        {
            if (sOrder[i] == x)
                index_x = i;
            else if (sOrder[i] == y)
                index_y = i;
        }

        if (index_x >= 0 && index_y >= 0)
        {
            if (index_x < index_y)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. We'll need to see your code in order to tell you why it isn't working...

Comment: Ok there's still a lot more information missing here.  What happens to strings that do not have one character in them?  Do you want to enforce this ordering on strings or individual characters?  etc...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var example = new string[]{"c", "a", "d", "b"};
var comparer = new CustomStringComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
Array.Sort(example, comparer);

...

class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly IComparer<string> _baseComparer;
    public CustomStringComparer(IComparer<string> baseComparer)
    {
        _baseComparer = baseComparer;
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (_baseComparer.Compare(x, y) == 0)
            return 0;

        // "b" comes before everything else
        if (_baseComparer.Compare(x, "b") == 0)
            return -1;
        if (_baseComparer.Compare(y, "b") == 0)
            return 1;

        // "c" comes next
        if (_baseComparer.Compare(x, "c") == 0)
            return -1;
        if (_baseComparer.Compare(y, "c") == 0)
            return 1;

        return _baseComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this do a stackoverflow? You should have wrote `if(x==y)return 0;` instead of `if (_baseComparer.Compare(x, y) == 0) return 0;`, which would result in recursion. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Nice solution.
Its performances can be slightly improved avoiding to call twice
```_baseComparer.Compare(x, y)```

Comment: What if a string is empty or NULL ?

Comment: @prototype0815 for the current culture comparer, null is considered less than an empty string, and an empty string is less than any non-empty string.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way is to substitute integers for the strings.

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int ix = x == "b" ? 0 : x == "c" ? 1 : 2;
        int iy = y == "b" ? 0 : y == "c" ? 1 : 2;
        return ix.CompareTo(iy);
    }
}

var example = new List<string> { "c", "b", "a", "d", "foo", "", "1", "e"};
example.Sort(new MyComparer());
foreach (var s in example)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

> Output:
>
> b
>   c
>
> 1
>   e
>   a
>   d
>   foo

Note that this isn't a stable sort. If you need a stable sort, there's a little more work involved.

Comment: With the same comparer, Linq's `OrderBy` does a stable sort: `var ordered = example.OrderBy(s => s, new MyComparer());`. But in the case you might as well say `.OrderBy(s => s == "b" ? 0 : s == "c" ? 1 : 2)` directly (although I don't like nesting `?:` operators).