# Sort list of string of format "1.23.23.3"

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have a list of strings

```
Dim myList as new List(Of String)

1.7 
1.8 
1.9 
1.10    
1.10.1.1
1.10.1.2
1.10.1.3
1.7.1.1
1.7.1.2
1.7.1.3
1.7.1.4
```

and I want to order them

```
1.7 
1.7.1.1
1.7.1.2
1.7.1.3  
1.7.1.4
1.8 
1.9 
1.10    
1.10.1.1
1.10.1.2
1.10.1.3
```

using

```
myList.Sort( comparer here? )
```

how do I write an simple comparer function?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975698/implementing-custom-icomparer-with-string)  to get started.

Comment: You're welcome. If you get stuck somehow, just update your question with the relevant code-snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a bit of work you could also use [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of String:

```
Dim versions As New List(Of Version) From {New Version("1.7"),
                                           New Version("1.8"),
                                           New Version("1.9"),
                                           New Version("1.10"),
                                           New Version("1.10.1.1"),
                                           New Version("1.10.1.2"),
                                           New Version("1.10.1.3"),
                                           New Version("1.7.1.1"),
                                           New Version("1.7.1.2"),
                                           New Version("1.7.1.3"),
                                           New Version("1.7.1.4")}

versions.Sort()
For Each v As Version In versions
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
            return str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
    });
```

or

```
Collections.sort(myList, (String str1, String str2) -> {return str1.compareTo(str2);}); //java 8
```

Comment: It is not that helpful to reply to a VB.Net tagged questions with C# syntax unless the C# code has direct equivalence in VB.