# How to sort an array of objects based on a property in custom order in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the following code

```
CustomerModel[] customerModel ;

customerModel = GetCustomerModel(customerReport);
```

Now this `CustomerModel`  class has a string property called `DealType` with possible values of `"CostOnly","Edlp","NonPromoted","Periodic"`.

All I want is to sort the customerModel array order by DealType property in the follwing order.

```
"NonPromoted",
"Edlp",
"Periodic",
"CostOnly"
```

What is the most optimal approach to solve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975698/implementing-custom-icomparer-with-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort by the index of an item in list of sequential custom order like this:

```
List<string> sortOrderList = new List<string>()
{
   "NonPromoted",
   "Edlp",
   "Periodic",
   "CostOnly"
};

 customerModel = customerModel.OrderBy(x=> sortOrderList.IndexOf(x.DealType)).ToArray();
```

This sorts each element by its order in the `sortOrderList`

Another option would be to use Array.Sort() to do in-Place sorting:

```
Array.Sort(customerModel, (x, y) => sortOrderList.IndexOf(x.DealType) - 
                                    sortOrderList.IndexOf(y.DealType));
```