# Linq with DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list "Sites" with one of the items as "From" and "To". It is defined as string and is in the format "MM/yyyy". When I try to sort the list based on the year, I'm facing a small problem.

Data for "From" and "To" is

```
01/2012
04/2012
01/2013
06/2012
```

When I sort the list by using orderby, the output I'm getting is

```
01/2012
01/2013
04/2012
06/2012
```

which is incorrect.

```
List<Site> List = new List<Site>();
                DataSet DS = ClientDB.Sites(Id);
                if (DS.HasTable0AndRows())
                {
                    IEnumerable<DataRow> _DataRow = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                   List = _DataRow.Select(x => new Site()
                    {
                        FileNum = x["File_Num"].ToString(),
                        From = x["From"].ToString(),
                        To = x["To"].ToString(),
                    }).ToList();
                }
                return List.OrderBy(x => x.FileNum).ToList();
            }
```

I understand that I have to use `DateTime.Parse` inorder to convert the From and To but how do I use the `DateTime.Parse` in the above case when i return the list?

Comment: You could implement a custom comparer, although it seems like an overkill to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975698/implementing-custom-icomparer-with-string

Comment: What is FileNum data type?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi, it's `string`.

Answer (score 5):

You need custom comparer.

```
class DateComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        var a_date = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "MM/yyyy", null);
        var b_date = DateTime.ParseExact(b, "MM/yyyy", null);
        return a_date.CompareTo(b_date);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
return List.OrderBy(x => x.From, new DateComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how it is working in the above solution?

Comment: You can pass custom comparer to the `OrderBy` function. This comparer will be used to compare items during sorting. My `DateComparer` converts `string` values to the `DateTime` using `DateTime.ParseExact` and returns result of dates comparison.

Please note that my solution is not optimal from the performance side. It will be better to convert dates once as proposed by Thomas D. If you still need string representation, you can use additional fields to store dates as `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
List<Site> List = new List<Site>();
DataSet DS = ClientDB.Sites(Id);
if (DS.HasTable0AndRows())
{
  IEnumerable<DataRow> _DataRow = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
  List = _DataRow.Select(x => new Site()
  {
    FileNum = x["File_Num"].ToString(),
    From = DateTime.ParseExact(x["From"].ToString(), "mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    To = DateTime.ParseExact(x["To"].ToString(), "mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
  }).ToList();
}
return List.OrderBy(x => x.From).ToList();
```

I am assuming that you want the `From` and `To` of type `DateTime` instead of `string`.

If you want to keep the types to be strings then you should use Uladzimir Palekh answer.

Comment: How do i handle null values in this case?

Comment: @ananthreddy, it depends from what you want to do with nulls. Now your sample code will fail. But you always can use nullables to store nulls.

Comment: @ananthreddy another possibility would be to use the TryParseExact method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is not solved yet use this:

Add this function beside your method:

```
    public int Compare(string a)
    {
        string[] arr = a.Split('/');
        return int.Parse(arr[1] + arr[0]);
    }
```

And use like this sample:

```
     List<string> dates = new List<string> { "01/2012", "04/2012", "01/2013", "06/2012" };
     dates = dates.OrderBy<string,int>(Compare).ToList();
```