# Is there any solution for this type of sorting in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an string array which contains filename such as

```
ODP001(SC00).csv, OPD003(SC00).csv, ODP002(SC00).csv, SPL001(SC00).csv, SPL002(SC01).csv, ODP003(SC01).csv, ODP01(SC01).csv, ODP(SC02).csv
```

which should be sorted as :

```
SPL001(SC00).csv  
ODP001(SC00).csv
ODP002(SC00).csv
ODP003(SC00).csv

SPL002(SC01).csv
ODP001(SC01).csv
ODP002(SC01).csv
ODP003(SC01).csv
```

Explanation: `SC00` and `SC01` is the family/Group name. And in that `SPL` is the parent and `ODP` being a child.

I am very confused how to sort this type of array. Can any body please help me?

Comment: You can create a custom string comparer - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975698/implementing-custom-icomparer-with-string. You would need to extract the family group name & compare that - then compare the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient or robust way, but this

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] strArr = new string[]
    {
        "ODP001(SC00).csv", 
        "ODP003(SC00).csv", 
        "ODP002(SC00).csv",
        "SPL001(SC00).csv",
        "SPL002(SC01).csv",
        "ODP003(SC01).csv",
        "ODP001(SC01).csv",
        "ODP(SC02).csv"
    };

    var sorted = strArr
        .OrderBy(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf("(")))
        .ThenByDescending(s => s.Substring(0,3))
        .ThenBy(s => s.Substring(3));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", sorted));
}
```

would display:

```
SPL001(SC00).csv
ODP001(SC00).csv
ODP002(SC00).csv
ODP003(SC00).csv
SPL002(SC01).csv
ODP001(SC01).csv
ODP003(SC01).csv
ODP(SC02).csv
```

Of course you could create a string comparer, or a class which could look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string filename)
    {
        // initialize the fields according to the filename (for example:)
        int typeLength = 3;
        int indexOpen = filename.IndexOf("(");
        int indexClose = filename.IndexOf(")");

        Type = filename.Substring(0,typeLength);
        int.TryParse(filename.Substring(typeLength,indexOpen-typeLength),out Order);
        int.TryParse(filename.Substring(indexOpen+3, indexClose-indexOpen-2),out SCOrder);
    }

    public string Type {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;}
    public int SCOrder {get;set;}
}
```

And then:

```
strArr.Select(s => new MyClass(s))
      .OrderBy(o => o.SCOrder)
      .ThenByDescending(o => o.Type)
      .ThenBy(o => o.Order);
```